# Find the set of points for which :

Tags: complex-analysis

So, I have to find the set of points for which

$\frac\pi4 <\arg(z+i)<\frac\pi2$

so $z=x+i\times y$

and I'm thinking about finding the tangent of every side

$\tan(\frac\pi4) <\tan[\arg(z+1)]<\frac\pi2$

where do we go now? :)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Try to look at this problem geometrically. A complex number $z$ has $\arg(z)\in\left(\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ if it is in the second slice of the complex plane (where I mean: cut $\mathbb{C}$ in $8$ slices as if it were a cake, take the second going counterclockwise). What does the function $z\mapsto z+i$ do geometrically?

Comment: I don't inted to be rude,but I can't write it that way in my exam...I need it in a long,algebric way..

Comment: @Mathfreak Yes, but my answer is a hint on how to see the problem in order to gain an intuition on what the solution should look like, which very often helps when doing the formal calculations. Also, you can make things a bit more formal and basically say exactly what I did ;)

Comment: Aber du bist eigentlich so lustig Daniel.

Comment: Ah Im getting my question downvoted now.Awesome.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you want your solution set to look like.

One route you can go:

Let $w = z+i$. Then the solution to $\dfrac{\pi}{4} <\operatorname{Arg}(w)<\dfrac{\pi}2$ is clearly $z+i=w=r(\cos\theta + i\sin\theta)$ where $r>0$ and $\dfrac{\pi}{4} <\theta<\dfrac{\pi}2$.

So, $z\in\{q\mid q=r(\cos\theta + i\sin\theta)-i,\, r>0,\dfrac{\pi}{4} <\theta<\dfrac{\pi}2\}$ is one way to represent the solution set.

---

If you want to represent the solution set in terms of $z$'s real and imaginary parts:

Let $z=x+iy$.

Note that since $\dfrac{\pi}{4} <\operatorname{Arg}(z+i)<\dfrac{\pi}2$, $z+i$ or $x+(y+1)i$ lies in the first quadrant and so $x>0$.

Again, since $\operatorname{Arg}(z+i)$ is in the first quadrant, $\operatorname{Arg}(z+i)=\tan^{-1} \dfrac{y+1}{x}$, so

$\dfrac{\pi}{4} <\operatorname{Arg}(z+i) \implies \tan\dfrac{\pi}4<\dfrac{y+1}x \implies x<y+1$.

To complete the proof you should show that $z=x+iy$ and $0<x<y+1$ implies $\dfrac{\pi}4<\operatorname{Arg}(z+i)<\dfrac{\pi}2$.

Comment: In my book it says that the answer should be x>0,1+y>x...this is why I tried to turn this into a tangent..